# Include columns from table-valued function in T-SQL query results

Tags: sql-server-2012

Let's say I have a table with a bunch of addresses:

| Address |
| --- |
| 10 Smith St |
| 20 Jones St |

I have a function that will take a provided string address and return a table with separate columns for each address component, e.g.:

| Number | Street |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | Smith St |

and I want to then run the function across all addresses and return a single table with the parsed columns included:

| Address | Number | Street |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 Smith St | 10 | Smith St |
| 20 Jones St | 20 | Jones St |

This is a simplified example because the parsing function might do some trickier stuff, so it has to be a function.

Any ideas??

Comment: What is the question actually ? You mention you already have a function that parse the `Address` into `Number` and `Street`. Any issue using that to get what you want ?

Answer (score 0):

Sigh, should have looked a little harder, I needed CROSS APPLY:

https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/tsql-user-defined-functions-ten-questions-you-were-too-shy-to-ask/#second

So in my example it would be:

select
s.Address,
p.*
from
source s
cross apply [dbo].parse_address p

Comment: That's not going to work unless your function is a Table Valued Function, and you pass in parameters